# Is there any way to get unique hardware ID on android devices?

Tags: android, hardware-id

Right now my algorithm based only on IMEI. And here is the problem: some devices doesn't have radio module, so they also doesn't have IMEI
I need unique parameters ( CPU ID, flash ID, MAC etc) to generate ID without using IMEI.
And how to get them with Java. Preferably without Root
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use `Build.SERIAL` to get the unique serial number of an android device. This will return a string value. In emulator this code may return the string "unknown". But try it with a device. It really works... :)

```
String id=Build.SERIAL;
```

Comment: this method will not work on API level less than 9(Android 2.2.3)

Comment: This serial never changes? Even after factory reset or update OS? Its unique for each device?

Answer (score 2):

ANDROID_ID

More specifically, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID. This is a 64-bit quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots. It is reset when the device is wiped.

ANDROID_ID seems a good choice for a unique device identifier. There are downsides: First, it is not 100% reliable on releases of Android prior to 2.2 (“Froyo”). Also, there has been at least one widely-observed bug in a popular handset from a major manufacturer, where every instance has the same ANDROID_ID.

[This could help you](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `android.os.Build.getSerial()` instead of `android.os.Build.SERIAL`

> `android.os.Build.SERIAL` --> This field was deprecated in API level O. Use getSerial() instead.
>   Source:
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use  the Setting.secure which is inbuilt to get the device id. this device ID is fixed till you reset the factory setting.

```
 Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

This is the unique Id of your device which is stable till you reset to the factory setting.

Answer (score -2):

below code can help you to get your device id

```
 String ts = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(ts);
    String imsi = mTelephonyMgr.getSubscriberId();
    String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: My device doesn't have radio module, so getSubscriberId() and getDeviceId() returns NULL